# WCF client console application deploying

Tags: wcf, client, console-application

Assuming serviceUrl is read from exe.config ( app.config in IDE )

```
 var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
 ...    
 client = new ContentServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(serviceURL));
```

Do I just need exe itself ( given no dependencies ) and exe.config for this client to invoke service on other box. I generated service reference when running service locally , looks like all those files purely for parameterless service call from IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

- .NET 3.0 or higher
- your EXE and exe.config
- network connectivity

and yes - that's all you need to call a service on a remote machine. The WCF runtime and all are part of .NET (3.0 or higher).